# How can I get the fieldnames of the PK (@Id) of a JPA @Entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0, primary-key

I'm using JPA2 (Hibernate 4) and have a bunch of @Entity classes with my PKs defined using @Id.  How can I programatically retrieve the fieldnames of the PKs of each entity class?

The business case for this is that I want to use Spring's [BeanUtils.copyProperties](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html) method to copy over entity objects, but want to make sure that I ignore the id fields of my entities while copying.

Is there a way to find this information?  Does JPA provide this information?  I realize that I can use reflection to go through every class, but hoped there would be an easier solution.  I looked into scanning the `PropertyDescriptor`s of the class, but cannot seem to find any method on the PropertyDescriptor that would give me the annotations of a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@PersistenceUnit
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

Metamodel metamodel = emf.getMetamodel();
metamodel.entity(MyEntity.class).getId();
```